# Is it possible to use Chrome's Built-In Roboto Font on Chrome Extension Popup Panels?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webfonts

If you open Chrome Extensions in Chrome via the following URL...

`chrome://extensions/`

...you'll notice that the font used on the page is Roboto, and it loads Roboto even if the computer doesn't have Roboto font installed as a system font.

So my question is, through some special Chrome Extension manifest setting,  HTML setting in the HEAD, as well as specifying Roboto font-family in the CSS, can a Chrome Extension popup panel take advantage of this font even without having to download the font from Google Web Fonts? It just seems like a waste of time to have to download a font that Google's Chrome already ships with and which its own settings pages take advantage of.

Comment: Nope. Chrome has quite a few things built-in (like CodeMirror or the fonts) which we can't use.

Comment: @wOxxOm You could formulate your answer into a real answer and then gain reputation with that.